# How can I set page animation boolean to false using Prism NavigateAsync()?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

How can I turn on page transition animation when using Prism NavigateAsync()?
The XamarinForms PushAsync has a Boolean you can set to false, east as that. How can I don that in Prism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Prism you would be using the `NavigationService` class in your `ViewModel`, if so, the method `NavigateAsync` has an extra input parameter you can use to toggle this! It's called `animated`, so if you want to disable the animation just use following code example:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NonModalSubPage", animated: false)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Simple enough, I have moved to using tabbedpages which has no animation, so can't confirm the solution but I will definitely need this in the future.